# Typescript recursively mapping object property types: object and array element types

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, data-binding

**UPDATE 1 -> SEE BELOW**

given the following interfaces

```
interface Model {
    bla: Child1;
    bwap: string;
}
interface Child1 {
    blu: Child2[];
}
interface Child2 {
    whi: string;
}
```

I am trying to write a function that will essentially be used like so:

```
let mapper = path<Model>("bla")("blu");
let myPropertyPath = mapper.path; //["bla", "blu"]
```

Function call x only accepts arguments that are keys of the type found at level x in the object hierarchy.

I have a working version of this, inspired by RafaelSalguero's post found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12290#issuecomment-305939047), and it looks like this:

```
interface IPathResult<TRoot, TProp> {
    <TSubKey extends keyof TProp>(key: TSubKey): IPathResult<TRoot, TProp[TSubKey]>;
    path: string[];
}

function path<TRoot>() {
    return <TKey extends keyof TRoot>(key: TKey) => subpath<TRoot, TRoot, TKey>([], key);
}

function subpath<TRoot, T, TKey extends keyof T>(parent: string[], key: TKey): IPathResult<TRoot, T[TKey]> {
    const newPath = [...parent, key];
    const x = (<TSubKey extends keyof T[TKey]>(subkey: TSubKey) => subpath<TRoot, T[TKey], TSubKey>(newPath, subkey)) as IPathResult<TRoot, T[TKey]>;
    x.path = newPath;
    return x;
}
```

A little more context is in order here to see where I'm going with this: I'm writing a binding library for use with (p)react. Drawing inspiration from Abraham Serafino's guide, found [here](https://objectpartners.com/2017/04/24/two-way-data-binding-in-reactjs-part-i/): his uses plain dotted strings to describe a path; I want to have type safety when doing it.
So an `IPathResult<TRoot, TProp>` instance could be read like: this gives me a path starting from `TRoot` that results in any property down the line of type `TProp`.

An example of its usage would be (without the implementation details)

```
<input type="text" {...bind.text(s => s("bwap")) } />
```

where the `s` parameter is `path<TState>()` and `TState = Model`.
The `bind.text` function would return a `value` property and an `onChange` handler that would call the component's `setState` method, setting the value found through the path we mapped to the new value.

This all works wonderfully, until you throw array properties in the mix.
Let's say I want to render inputs for all elements found in the `blu` property on the `Child1` interface. What I would like to do is to write something like this:

```
let mapper = path<Model>("bla"); //IPathResult<Model, Child1>
for(let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { //just assume there are 2 elements in that array
    let myPath = mapper("blu", i)("whi"); //IPathResult<Model, string>, note: we're writing "whi", which is a key of Child2, NOT of Array<Child2>
}
```

So, the mapper calls would have an overload that takes an extra argument for array `TProp`, specifying the index of the element in the array to bind to, and the most important part: **the next mapper call would require keys of the array *element* type, NOT the array type itself!**

So plugging that into the actual binding example, this could become:

```
<input type="text" {...bind.text(s => s("bla")("blu", i)("whi")) } />
```

So this is where I'm stuck: even disregarding actual implementation, how do I define that overload in the `IPathResult<TRoot, TProp>` interface? The following would be the gist of it, but doesn't work:

```
interface IPathResult<TRoot, TProp> {
    <TSubKey extends keyof TProp>(key: TSubKey): IPathResult<TRoot, TProp[TSubKey]>;
    <TSubKey extends keyof TProp>(key: TSubKey, index: number): IPathResult<TRoot, TProp[TSubKey][0]>;
    path: string[];
}
```

Typescript doesn't accept the `TProp[TSubKey][0]` part, saying that `type 0 cannot be used to index type TProp[TSubKey]`. I guess that makes sense since there is no way for the typing system to know that `TProp[TSubKey]` *can* be indexed that way, it's simply not defined.

If I write an interface like this:

```
interface IArrayPathResult<TRoot, TProp extends Array<TProp[0]>> {
    <TSubKey extends keyof TProp[0]>(key: TSubKey): IPathResult<TRoot, TProp[0][TSubKey]>;
    path: string[];
}
```

that allows me to actually type this:

```
const result: IArrayPathResult<Model, Child2[]> = null;
result("whi"); //woohoow!
```

That's a pointless example in itself of course, but just goes to show that it IS possible to get that array element type returned. But `TProp` is now defined as always being an array, which is obviously not going to be the case.

I feel like I'm pretty close to getting this, but bringing it all together is eluding me.
Any ideas?

**Important note**: there are no instance arguments to infer types from, and there aren't supposed to be any!

**UPDATE 1:**

Using Titian's [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49794969/2830733) with conditional types, I can use the syntax I wanted.
However, some type information seems to have gone missing:

```
const mapper = path<Model>();
const test: IPathResult<Model, string> = mapper("bla"); //doesn't error!
```

This should not work, because the `mapper("bla")` call returns `IPathResult<Model, Child1>`, which is not assignable to `IPathResult<Model, string>`!
If you remove one of the 2 method overloads in the `IPathResult` interface, the code above *does* correctly error, saying that *"Type 'Child1' is not assignable to type 'string'."*

So close! Any more ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional types to extract the item element, and ensure that the array version is only called with array keys:

```
type KeysOfType<T, TProp> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends TProp? P : never}[keyof T];
type ElementTypeIfArray<T> = T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never

interface IPathResult<TRoot, TProp> {
    <TSubKey extends KeysOfType<TProp, Array<any>>>(key: TSubKey, index: number): IPathResult<TRoot, ElementTypeIfArray<TProp[TSubKey]>>;
    <TSubKey extends keyof TProp>(key: TSubKey): IPathResult<TRoot, TProp[TSubKey]>;
    path: string[];
}

let mapper = path<Model>()("bla")("blu", 1)("whi"); // works
let mapper2 = path<Model>()("bla", 1) // error bla not an array key
```

**Update**

Not sure why ts thinks `IPathResult<Model, string>` is compatible with `IPathResult<Model, Child1>`, if I remove the any of the overloads it indeed does report a compatibility error. Maybe it is a compiler bug, I might investigate it later if I get a chance. The simplest work around is to add a field to `IPathResult` that uses `TProp` directly to ensure incompatibility:

```
interface IPathResult<TRoot, TProp> {
    <TSubKey extends KeysOfType<TProp, Array<any>>>(key: TSubKey, index: number): IPathResult<TRoot, ElementTypeIfArray<TProp[TSubKey]>>;
    <TSubKey extends keyof TProp>(key: TSubKey): IPathResult<TRoot, TProp[TSubKey]>;
    path: string[];
    __: TProp;
}
```

Comment: Hot damn! Hadn't looked through the new features very well yet!
Thanks man, that's awesome, exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: I spoke too soon, please have another look at my post, "Update 1". So close!

Comment: Ah yes, typescript and unused generics don't play well half the time, true :)
It's still odd though seeing as intellisense does report `IPathResult<Model, Child1>` being returned, so the type is definitely known.
Let me know if you find anything, I'll have another look as well. It might turn out to be something for the typescript github forums.
In the meantime I'm marking this as the accepted answer; that extra property really doesn't get in the way of anything :)